# How can I create a java class with two generics?

Tags: java, generics

Is it possible to create a Java class that has 2 generics? Basically what I am looking to do is create a `Class A`. But I only want `Class A` to use `Class B` and(or) `Class C`. I was thinking wildcard but that leaves more open than I would like.

I was looking for a way to to `public class A <T OR T>`

Example;

```
Test = new A <B>();
Test 2 = new A <C>();
```

How could I accomplish this?

Comment: Do B and C have a common superclass/interface? If so, then use that instead. Like `public class A<T extends D>` where D is the superclass or common interface of B and C.

Comment: You can put a marker interface on B and C and make your class a generic of the interface.

Comment: `public class A<T> {...}` and then `A<B> test = new A<B>()` and `A<C> test2 = new A<C>()`

Comment: @ManoDestra No the 2 classes do not share any superclass. At least not at this time.

Comment: @azurefrog I don't quite follow, could you explain a bit?

Comment: @ianc1215 Either force the two classes in question to share an interface, if you absolutely wish to lock down which classes you can use in your generic. Or simply just allow for one generic type and allow any class to be part of it.

Comment: @ManoDestra I should be able to check if the class that is being used is an instance of a class right? That would allow me to exclude certain classes.

Comment: Can the generic type be constrained to exactly two unrelated classes? Straightforward answer is no.

Comment: You might want to ask yourself what you're trying to accomplish with such a design though since it somewhat flies in the face of the purpose of generics.

Comment: @pvg That's a good idea, right now I am just scratching this on a notepad at work. I will need to put a little more into this tonight.

Comment: @ianc1215 Not if you want to enforce this business rule at compile time, no. Simply make the two classes share an interface, then use T extends D in your generic class. Then, only classes that implement that interface will be allowed at compile time. See Aomine's answer below for the specifics of how to do it. If you make it an interface, then you can easily implement that interface in other classes later and they will then be allowed to be added to your generic class, making the generic useful.

Answer (score 2):

Create an `interface` e.g.

```
interface IsomeName{...}
```

Then your class `A` should be something along the lines of this:

```
class A <T extends IsomeName>{...}
```

You should then let the other classes share the same interface:

```
class B implements IsomeName{...}

class C implements IsomeName{...}
```

Which should enable you to instantiate it like so:

```
A<B> b = new A<>();
A<C> c = new A<>();
```

Comment: @YCF_L thanks for the edit! ^^.

Comment: oh no problem @Aominè you are welcome as always :)